# Does Hornetq recover already delivered messages?

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq

Pretty self-explanatory question: it seems that Jboss 7's embedded HornetQ attempts to recover transactions for already processed messages. Could it be the case? If so, is it fixed in later versions (Jboss 7 uses HornetQ 2.2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HornetQ (and all the message systems implements JMS or AMQP) will redeliver message that weren't acknowledged. If the server delivered it but you never acknowledged it.. the server will redeliver the message as soon as you recreate the consumer (either after a client failure or server crash).

I am not sure what you meant by "HornetQ attempts to recover transactions for already processed messages." So I will explain some of the TX semantics.

If you open a transaction, messages are acknwoledged as part of that transaction. If that TX commits the acks are confirmed and the message will be deleted from the server.

if that TX is prepared (never committed) the server will hold these messages until the server decides what to do with the TX. (recovery process from the Transaction Manager).

So, the key to your answer is acknowledgment versus delivered.

with hornetQ specifically there's an acknowledgement mode call Pre-ACK where the message leaves the server as soon as delivered to your client. You can try that but messages will never be redelivered after hardware failures, so be careful and research what it's doing before you take that decision.